# Google Sign-In not working using Firebase AuthUI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin, firebaseui

I have enabled providers at https://console.firebase.google.com

[image]

I have dependencies section

```
dependencies {
    ...    
    //Firebase Dependencies
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'   

    // FirebaseUI Auth only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.4.3'    

}
```

My code for SignIn is

```
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
 private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
 private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 615;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null){
                    // empty
                } else {                   
                    startActivityForResult(
                            AuthUI.getInstance()
                                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                    .setProviders(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER,
                                            AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER)
                                    .build(),
                            RC_SIGN_IN);
                }
            }
        };

  }
```

at this point I'm able to sign-in successfully using Email/Password, but Google sign-in is not working. Any help is appreciated.

### UPDATE

onActivityResult is

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Signed in...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Signed in canceled...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what happens when you choose google sign in

Comment: Only shows progress dialog and dialog disappears nothing happens afterwords

Comment: did you do followed this to implemet google sign in https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Comment: show your onactivtiyresult code and method where you initiate google signin also

Comment: see my __update__

Comment: I'm using `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth`

Comment: I was following along Udacity.com videos of Firebase in a Weekend, please help me

Answer (score 0):

Looks like dependency on play services is missing: this is from Firebase doc page - see in bold:

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:**play-services**-auth:11.4.0'